# what is the big O of a for loop that increments by i*2 each iteration and terminates when <n?

Tags: c++

I know if n= 0 the loop runs 0 times

```
n = 1 the loop runs 1 time
n = 2 the loop runs 2 times
n = 3 the loop runs 2 times
n = 4 the loop runs 3 times
```

and so on, but I dont know how to generalize it.

here's the for loop

```
  for(int i = 1 ; i< n; i*=2)
```

{}

Comment: You could plot iterations per N and see what kind of curve you get. Does it follow log(N), N, N*Log(N), N*N, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be O(log n). You cut the collection in half each time, so to speak.